# Grok filter is not being parsed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am trying to add Modsecurity OSSEC logs to ELK. The logs are sent to the ELK server using filebeat with the following prospector:

```
-
  paths:      
    - /var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.log

  document_type: ossec-log
  multiline:
    pattern: '^\*\*'
    negate: true   
    match: before
    max_lines: 20
    timeout: 5s
```

On the ELK server, I created a custom logstash config in conf.d with the following content:

```
filter {
  if [type] == "ossec-log" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "(?m)\*\* Alert %{DATA:timestamp_seconds}:%{SPACE}%{WORD}?%{SPACE}\- %{DATA:ossec_group},\n%{YEAR} %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{HOSTNAME}\-\>%{DATA:reporting_source}\nRule: %{NONNEGINT:rule_number} \(level %{NONNEGINT:severity}\) \-\> '%{DATA:signature}'\nSrc IP: %{IP:src_ip}\n\[modsecurity\] \[client %{IP:src_ip}\] \[domain %{DATA:FQDN}\] \[%{NONNEGINT:DenyCode}\] \[%{DATA:LogLocation}\]  \[file \"%{DATA:RuleConfig}\"\] \[line \"%{NONNEGINT:LineNumber}\"\] \[id \"%{NONNEGINT:RuleID}\"\] \[rev \"%{NONNEGINT:RevID}\"\] \[msg \"%{DATA:message}\"\] \[severity \"%{DATA:severity_text}\"\]%{GREEDYDATA}"]
    }
  }
}
```

The data that it should match against is structured like:

```
** Alert 1471539036.4425320: mail  - modsecurity,access_denied,
2016 Aug 18 18:50:36 myserver->/var/log/httpd/audit_log
Rule: 397989 (level 7) -> 'Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: MSIE 6.0 detected (Disable if you want to allow MSIE 6) '
Src IP: 127.127.127.127
[modsecurity] [client 127.127.127.127] [domain mydomain.org] [403] [/apache/20160818/20160818-1850/20160818-185034-YWhIuJT7g-sAAHaRtlsAAAAv]  [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/20_asl_useragents.conf"] [line "369"] [id "397989"] [rev "1"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: MSIE 6.0 detected (Disable if you want to allow MSIE 6)"] [severity "WARNING"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "rx (MS Web Services Client Protocol|WormlyBot|webauth@cmcm\\.com)" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent" required.
```

This works in the grokdebugger, but somehow it is not being parsed in ELK. The log items are shown in ELK, with the correct type (ossec-log), but they seem to not be processed. The log entries are listed, but with the entire line dumped in "message", a tag called "beats_input_codec_plain_applied, _grokparsefailure", and none of the fields I defined in the grok are present.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 190816: I fixed it by switching the match brackets to braces and switching comma to => (match => { "message" => "grok pattern"). Later I also switched the filebeat config match directive from 'before' to 'after'.